# Outlook 2003 - emailing 'non declined' attendees to a meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

How do I email all 'Accepted' and 'Tentative' and 'not replied' attendees to a meeting in Outlook 2003 (ie just excluding those who have declined) ?

Does not seem to be an option for it..

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no 'in built' way to achieve this.

The following utility can be used instead though:

http://www.imibo.com/imidev/Exchange/imiap.htm